# Difference in upload limit on Wordpress and upload_max_filesize value in php.ini

Tags: php, wordpress, ini

I am having trouble uploading large images to Wordpress. When I try to add an image there is the message:

***Maximum upload file size: 2 MB***

When I upload an image over 2mb I get the error message:

***The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.***

I have checked the values by using phpinfo() and I can see that upload_max_filesize is set at 40M.

How can there be a difference? What else do I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of articles which might help you [the first](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/)  and [the second](http://wptheming.com/2009/07/upload_max_filesize/).

Why are you uploading large images? Are they for dsiplay on a page/post? Perhaps it would be better to reduce the file size prior to uploading.

Comment: The client's photos are about 2.5mb and taken from his camera and he doesn't have photo resizing software. So was hoping to fix it so Wordpress matched the allowed php.ini settings. Thanks for the articles, i've tried all of that before but it doesn't work.